# Insert ChangeLog entries in commit message?

Tags: magit

Is there a way to insert relevant entries from the ChangeLog into the Magit commit message? I'm thinking of how the built-in Emacs VC's C-c C-a (log-edit-insert-changelog) command works.

Comment: Most people do the opposite: generate the `ChangeLog` file with `git log` (or just tell people to use git or browse Github to see the change log).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but it's not very good. While you are writing a commit message, switch to the diff buffer and then press <kbd>C</kbd> on a hunk whose changes you want to describe. Then repeat for all such hunks... I said it wasn't very good.